# How to make vim forget all vestiges of a file that it opened?

Tags: filenames

I was editing `~/tmp/tmp.txt` and saved it to `NeatoPortDemo.bash` (with capitals).  I then wanted to change the file name to `neatoPortDemo.bash` (without leading capital).  Writing to `neatoPortDemo.bash` and issuing `:e neatoPortDemo.bash` puts me back into `NeatoPortDemo.bash`, i.e., the leading capital is retained -- not what I want.

I tried `:bdelete` to delete the buffer.  In Bash, I deleted `[Nn]eatoPortDemo.bash`. In Vim, I went to `~/tmp/tmp.txt` and wrote it to `neatoPortDemo.bash`.  I then used `netrw` to show the files and confirm that the desired file had no leading capital.  I also confirmed this in Bash.  When I descended into `neatoPortDemo.bash` from `netrw`, however, it again had a leading capital.

I am sure that this has to do with how the file system is defined in Cygwin.  That is not something that I want to confront as this time.

**Is there any way in Vim to erase all vestiges of `NeatoPortDemo.bash` so that `neatoPortDemo.bash` is recognized and retained?**

If I start a new instance of Vim, I lose all the information about the buffers, tabs, and subwindows.  I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

Comment: +1 for using the word vestiges in the title

Comment: @mattb: Flattered but puzzled....On a separate note, I found that I can start a new GVim instance by first issuing `:mksession! ~/session.x.vim` within Vim, followed by `gvim -S ~/session.x.vim` from the Bash command line.  The new instance has forgotten all vestiges of `NeatoPortDemo.bash`, allowing me to edit `neatoPortDemo.bash` (assuming that I deleted that buffer before creating `session.x.vim`).  It's such a trivial solution that I am unsure whether it should be posted as an answer (or whether this question should in fact be deleted)

Comment: I would post it as an answer - after all you were moved to post the question, so I assume at least some others will google it in the future. (I'll upvote the answer if it contains the word vestiges).

Comment: Thanks, but a much better informed answer was posted by (a different) "Matt".  I'll leave my "solution" in these here comments.

Comment: Yes ... "cache-ing", also, which I always forget about... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:h :bdelete` only sets the flag to hide a buffer from buffers list. To delete a buffer completely use `:h :bwipeout` instead.

Also note that Vim running on case-sensitive OS should normally have `:h 'fileignorecase'` option unset automatically. This should resolve all the troubles of this kind.

However, as CYGWIN/MSYS2 don't have a file system of its own, they simply re-use underlying Windows file system which is "case-insensitive/case-preserving" only. And so `:h 'fileignorecase'` will be rightfully set by Vim.

Comment: `fileignorecase` is indeed set, and `bwipeout` does indeed make Vim forget the filename with the leading capitalization, as desired.  Thanks!